# get a running total of dates in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a running list of dates which adds 6 weeks on to the date above it. So far my code gives me a start and end dates. I need to show the 6 week intervals between the start and end dates

```
aLearnerRef     startdate     enddate       reviewdate
------------------------------------------------------
399750423600    2013-11-27    2014-06-12    2014-01-08
399750423600    2013-11-27    2014-06-12    2014-02-19
399750423600    2013-11-27    2014-06-12    2014-04-02
399750423600    2013-11-27    2014-06-12    2014-05-14
```

I want it to loop until it gets to the last date before the enddate. I cant work out a possible way to do this. Here is what code I have so far:

```
SELECT a.aLearnerRef,  x.startdate, x.enddate
FROM aims a
inner join vStudyP s
on s.LearnerRef = a.aLearnerRef
join (SELECT aLearnerRef, min(learnstartdate) startdate, max(learnplannedenddate) enddate
        FROM aims
        GROUP BY aLearnerRef) x
on a.aLearnerRef = x.aLearnerRef
group by a.aLearnerRef,  x.startdate, x.enddate
```

Comment: I think, Recursive CTE is useful here. Will try out some code & share.

Answer (score 1):

try this code,

```
with cte as
(
select ak.akid,sdate,edate,DATEADD(WEEK,6,sdate) rdate from ak
Union All

select ak.akid,ak.sdate,ak.edate,DATEADD(WEEK,6,rdate) rdate from ak
inner join cte on  rdate between ak.sdate and ak.edate 
where  DATEADD(WEEK,6,rdate) between ak.sdate and ak.edate 


)
select * from CTE
```

If more than one records,

```
with cte as
    (
    select ak.akid,sdate,edate,DATEADD(WEEK,6,sdate) rdate from ak
    Union All

    select ak.akid,ak.sdate,ak.edate,DATEADD(WEEK,6,rdate) rdate from ak
    inner join cte on  rdate between ak.sdate and ak.edate 
    where  DATEADD(WEEK,6,rdate) between ak.sdate and ak.edate 
          and cte.akid = ak.akid

    )
    select * from CTE
```

link for demo,   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31d30/5

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. What if there are more than 1 record in ak?

Comment: So you want to follow same patter for each of them? If you want this ans for only one record you can apply where clause in both select statement. So it depends on your requirement.

Comment: I think it will work for more than one record also. Still will edit an & post 2nd option ny adding just 1 more condition. If you are satisfied with ans. please mark ans. as useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use the auxilliary numbers table:

```
SELECT a.aLearnerRef,  dateadd(day,n,a.startdate), a.enddate
FROM aims a
inner join numbers num
on n < datediff(day,startdate, enddate)
```